# How to push data from multiple sources/integrations for a single destination in stitch ETL Tool

Tags: etl, talend, freshdesk, stitch

How to push data from multiple sources/integrations to the single destination i.e (Postgresql) in Stitch Data ETL Tool.

I had tried to push data from multiple sources but was facing database issues. Can any one help me out with this issue